# What are the options available in Bluetooth earphones with display and multipoint connectivity

Tags: earphones

I am looking for Bluetooth earphones which:

1. Allows pairing with at least 3 devices (I know only 2 devices can be connected at a time)
2. Preferably has LCD display to see numbers/names being called and settings being changed.
3. Clip on design, that help the main unit and MOST of the cable to be concealed underneath clothes. (I don't want to show off in public places )

5 years back, I had bought Sony MW600 with above features and is no longer available. Thankfully, it still works, thought it's clip is broken and battery backup has been reduced to less than half, around 3-4 hours.

For the last 2 years, I have been using Sony SBH 52, but it can be paired with only 2 devices. I have been able to find other options from Sony only but they support only 2 devices.

What options do I have that meet my requirements - be it Sony or other?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

> *All Plantronics Bluetooth Headsets can pair with up to 4 different devices*

source: https://headsetplus.com/blog/plantronics-bluetooth-headset-multipoint-technology/

Now the caveat seems to be that you can `pair` to 4 devices, but only `connect` to two devices and `switch` between them.

I guess you should call their support department and have a chat.

Comment: Thanks Edwin. All of them satisfy at least my first criteria.